# calling ajax inside form before submit showing `Uncaught ReferenceError`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, python-3.x

I am trying to call an ajax function from inside a form to extract  value for the drop down.

`mypython.py`

```
@app.route('/new_data', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def new_data():
    #Filter data and return the data(data_list,filter_function_url) to myhtml.html file
```

`myhtml.html`

```
<div>
<form ....method="POST" action="{{url_for('submit_new_data')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ....
    ....
    <select id="selected_data" onchange='get_subdata_filters("{{ filter_function_url }}")'>
         <option disabled selected>Please Select Partner State</option>
          {% for f in data_list %}
          <option value="{{f}}">{{f}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
     </select>
</form>
</div>
```

`myjsfile.js`

This does work fine the value from the id `selected_data` from the `html file` and the `selected_option_data_filter_url` got from `html` `filter_function_url` does get displayed properly on the console without any error

```
function get_subdata_filters(selected_option_data_filter_url) {

  var selected_data = document.getElementById("selected_data").value;
  // make the user selected data into a dictionary/json
  var new_selected_data = {
    s_data:selected_data
  };
  console.log(new_selected_data);
  console.log(selected_option_data_filter_url);
}
```

When I add an `ajax` call inside my js function upto `select`

```
function get_subdata_filters(selected_option_data_filter_url) {

  var selected_data = document.getElementById("selected_data").value;
  // make the user selected data into a dictionary/json
  var new_selected_data = {
    s_data:selected_data
  };
  console.log(new_selected_data);
  console.log(selected_option_data_filter_url);
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          url: selected_option_data_filter_url,
          traditional: "true",
          async:false,
          timeout: 40000,
          data: JSON.stringify({new_selected_data}),
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(fselected_data){
            console.log(fselected_data)
          };
        });
}
```

I get this error
`Uncaught ReferenceError: get_subdata_filters is not defined` when I check the `console`

What is doing wrong?
How can I correct this?

Comment: Because there is an error in your ajax call, remove the `;` after the success and it should work. Also add a `;` after your `console.log()`

Comment: @Jbadminton Worked. Please answer below so that i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your `ajax` call.
Remove the `;` after the success and add an `;` after your `console.log()`

```
function get_subdata_filters(selected_option_data_filter_url) {

  var selected_data = document.getElementById("selected_data").value;
  // make the user selected data into a dictionary/json
  var new_selected_data = {
    s_data:selected_data
  };
  console.log(new_selected_data);
  console.log(selected_option_data_filter_url);
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          url: selected_option_data_filter_url,
          traditional: "true",
          async:false,
          timeout: 40000,
          data: JSON.stringify({new_selected_data}),
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(fselected_data){
            console.log(fselected_data);
          }
        });
}
```